# iOS 8 Keyboard - Issue with pushing the UITextField up when keyboard was shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a message like chat window. When the keyboard was shown, I would push the UITextField so it appears to be right above the keyboard. In iOS 7, it works fine, but it doesn't work on iOS 8. Here's my code

```
// Detect the keyboard events

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

// Listen to keyboard shown/hidden event and resize. 

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

        CGRect frame = self.textInputView.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= kbSize.height;
        self.textInputView.frame = frame;

        frame = self.myTableView.frame;
        frame.size.height -= kbSize.height;
        self.myTableView.frame = frame;
    }];
    [self scrollToTheBottom:NO];
}


- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
     NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
     CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

        CGRect frame = self.textInputView.frame;
        frame.origin.y += kbSize.height;
        self.textInputView.frame = frame;

        frame = self.myTableView.frame;
        frame.size.height += kbSize.height;
        self.myTableView.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What does it do?

Comment: @rdelmar: when the keyboard shown, it doesn't push the uitextfield above the keyboard - similar to the message view window of the iphone "message" app

Comment: @Andrew Smith, the issue was related to how the table view and the textInputView were added to the view.  Originally, I've added them using the interface builder tool and it works fine in iOS 7, but not in iOS 8. I've changed my code to add all ui components programmatically and things work now. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`, in order for your code to work, you should be using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

> UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey The key for an NSValue object
>   containing a CGRect that identifies the start frame of the keyboard in
>   screen coordinates. These coordinates do not take into account any
>   rotation factors applied to the window’s contents as a result of
>   interface orientation changes. Thus, you may need to convert the
>   rectangle to window coordinates (using the convertRect:fromWindow:
>   method) or to view coordinates (using the convertRect:fromView:
>   method) before using it.
>
> UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey The key for an NSValue object containing
>   a CGRect that identifies the end frame of the keyboard in screen
>   coordinates. These coordinates do not take into account any rotation
>   factors applied to the window’s contents as a result of interface
>   orientation changes. Thus, you may need to convert the rectangle to
>   window coordinates (using the convertRect:fromWindow: method) or to
>   view coordinates (using the convertRect:fromView: method) before using
>   it.